# How do I count word occurence from a list of urls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have list of urls in a JSON object in WordPress. I want to count the occurence of the second part of the url.

The code below currently gets the rest of the url after the prefix `https://www.example.co` . What I want to do next is the count the occurence of the second part of the url which is `cat1, cat3, cat2, xmlrpc.php`

```
var urlList = [
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat3/aa/bb/cc/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/xmlrpc.php",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 19, 2019"
  }
]

const paths = urlList.map(value => value.URL.replace('https://www.example.co', ''));

//console.log(paths);

paths.forEach(function(item) {
    var urlSecondPart = item.split("/")[1];
    console.log(urlSecondPart);
});
```

Do you know how can I achieve that with my current `forEach` loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match non-`/`s that come after the `.co/`:

```js
var urlList = [
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat3/aa/bb/cc/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/xmlrpc.php",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 19, 2019"
  }
]

const paths = urlList.map(
  ({ URL }) => URL.match(/\.co\/([^\/]+)/)[1]
);
console.log(paths);

const counts = paths.reduce((a, str) => {
  a[str] = (a[str] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(counts);
```

On newer engines, you can use lookbehind instead of extracting the capture group:

```
const paths = urlList.map(
  ({ URL }) => URL.match(/(?<=\.co\/)[^\/]+/)[0]
);
```

If you want to keep track of all full URLs used, reduce not only into a count, but also into an array of those full URLs:

```js
var urlList = [
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat3/aa/bb/cc/",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat2/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://www.example.co/xmlrpc.php",
    "Last crawled": "Jun 19, 2019"
  }
]

const getSecond = url => url.match(/\.co\/([^\/]+)/)[1];

const counts = urlList.reduce((a, { URL }) => {
  const second = getSecond(URL);
  if (!a[second]) {
    a[second] = { count: 0, fullUrls: [] };
  }
  a[second].count++;
  a[second].fullUrls.push(URL);
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(counts);
```

Comment: This looks good. Do you have any way to output each url's beside the count like `https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb cat1: 3` `https://www.example.co/cat1/aa/bb/cc/dd/ee cat1: 3`

Comment: Reduce into an object which has not only the count for the second string, but also an array of full URLs used, and push to the associated array on each iteration

Comment: Thank you for this. I was not able to to imagine your solution. All I thought was doing it inside the `forEach` loop